# Python image join

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I split the image 4 piece
I want to remake them with randomly placement.
For example : frame2_frame3_frame1_frame 4

```
image=cv2.imread("example.jpg") 
height, width, channels = image.shape
frame_1=image[1:int(height/2)+1,0:int(width/2)]
frame_2=image[1:int(height/2)+1,int(width/2)+1:int(width)+1]
frame_3=image[int(height/2)+1:int(height)+1,0:int(width/2)+1]
frame_4=image[int(height/2)+1:int(height)+1,int(width/2)+1:int(width)+1]
total=[frame_1+frame_2]
```

Thank you

Comment: So.. what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread("1.jpg") 

#resize image to make sure 4 pieces have the same dimension
image = cv2.resize(img, (400,400),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

height, width, channels = image.shape

frame_1=image[0:int(height/2),0:int(width/2)]
frame_2=image[0:int(height/2),int(width/2):int(width)]
frame_3=image[int(height/2):int(height),0:int(width/2)]
frame_4=image[int(height/2):int(height),int(width/2):int(width)]

new_image = np.empty_like(image)

new_image[0:int(height/2),0:int(width/2)] = frame_3
new_image[0:int(height/2),int(width/2):int(width)] = frame_2
new_image[int(height/2):int(height),0:int(width/2)] = frame_1
new_image[int(height/2):int(height),int(width/2):int(width)] = frame_4

cv2.imshow("image",image)
cv2.imshow("new_image",new_image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your attention,It's working on my photos , now I'm gonna try to make it randomly placement.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are absolutely intent on learning how to do this with Python, or whether you just want to get the job done. If it's the former, please just disregard my answer, if it's the latter, this is pretty simple just in the Terminal with **ImageMagick** without needing to write any code.

Starting with this image `colorwheel.png`:

[image]

Run the following command in Terminal (or Command Prompt on Windows):

```
magick colorwheel.png -crop 2x2@ -swap 0,3 miff:- | magick montage -geometry +0+0 miff:- result.png
```

[image]

The command says... *"open `colorwheel.png` and split into 4 equal pieces. Swap the first and third pieces and write the four images out in MIFF format. Pass that into ImageMagick's `montage` command and join the images together with no gaps between them."*

---

Or if you want to cut into 16 pieces and get jiggy:

```
magick colorwheel.png -crop 4x4@ -swap 0,14 -swap 1,12 -swap 6,9  miff:- | magick montage -geometry +0+0 miff:- result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your attention,It's really useful but I'm intent on learning how to do this with Python.

Comment: Cool - no problems. Good luck with your project!

Comment: I do not know if this will be of interest, but I have a bash unix Imagemagick script called shuffle at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php that does this kind of processing and more.

Comment: `@Mark Setchell` Send my your email address if you don't mind. You can find mine on my web site above. I think we communicated some time ago, but I lost your email address. Nothing important. I just want to have it available. Thanks

Comment: @fmw42 I just Emailed you.